# How to call a partial view having model in main view both views are having different model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a main view in which i want to call a partial view , but my partial view is not static it is having model and both the models (main view model and partial view model are different) not when i write `@Html.Partial("MyPartialView")` 
it says that object reference is not set to an instance it mean

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set 
to an instance of an object.
```

it means i need to call the controller method as well along with partial view how to achieve that basically in partial view i am listing my records .

Answer (score 1):

you can prepare your partial View Model in the action of your main View.
you should create a ViewModel that have two properties, one of them is model for your main view and the other is the model for your partial view. like this :

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<MainModel> MainModels { get; set; }  
    public List<PartialViewModel> PartialViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult MainView()  
{  
    ViewModel mymodel = new ViewModel();  
    mymodel.MainModels = GetMainModels();  
    mymodel.PartialViewModels  = GetPartialViewModels();  
    return View(mymodel);  
}
```

View code

```
@model ViewModel   
...
PartialView("_Partial", Model.PartialViewModels);
```

Properties must not necessarily be of the list type. They can be of the same entity. It depends on your needs

Comment: Thanks for helping me somayeh I have created my view model as shown below
```
public class StudentViewModel
    {
        public  List<Student> students { get; set; }
        public List<Student_Experience> Student_experience { get; set; }
    }
```
but after that my view is not accepting this 
List<student> does not contain a definition for'STudent_LName' and no accessible extension method 'Student_LName' accepting a first argument of type List<student> could be found are you missing a using directive

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.students.Student_LName, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Last Name *", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.students[0].Student_LName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```
then it did not show error 
issue is i have list in viewmodel and on view it ask me to do the model binding with [] syntax , it is my index view list view i mean

Comment: Or if you need Student only, you can define your viewmodel like this :
public class StudentViewModel 
{ 
 public Student student { get; set; } 
 public List<Student_Experience> Student_experience { get; set; } 
}

Comment: Your welcaome buddy,
Do you need List<Student> in your Main View or you need Student?
if you need List of student you should use foreach to process per student in your view like this :
@foreach (var item in Model.students)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student_LName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.....)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }